# express-validator wrong check

Tags: express-validator

I'm using express-validator 5.3.1. I defined password check like this :

```
check('password')
  .not().isEmpty().withMessage('Password can\'t be null')
  .isString()
  .isLength({ min: 8 }),
check('retypePassword')
  .not().isEmpty().withMessage('Password can\'t be null')
  .isString().withMessage('Password must be a string')
  .custom((value, { req }) => {
    if(value.trim() !== req.body.password.trim()) {
      throw new Error ('Password confirmation does not match password');
    }
  }),
```

For testing, I send same password and retypePassword ('password') and got error :

> [
>       {
>           "location": "body",
>           "param": "retypePassword",
>           "value": "password",
>           "msg": "Invalid value"
>       }
>   ]

I defined message with all error of retypePassword, so what's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement a `custom` validation you have to return `true` if the validation succeed, otherwise you will get the "Invalid value" error message. So you just add a `return true;` statement like this

```
.custom((value, { req }) => {
    if(value.trim() !== req.body.password.trim()) {
        throw new Error ('Password confirmation does not match password');
    }
    return true;
})
```

Comment: wow, it worked. I followed example (https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html) and they didn't say anything about this

Comment: Hi @DươngKingfisher, thanks for pointing out this flaw in the docs :) I'm the maintainer of express-validator and will fix it.

Comment: Return `resolve`, `reject` in case of promise.